# How to manage a Webservice timeout in System.Reactive

Tags: .net-3.5, system.reactive

I am starting out with System.Reactive and loving the simplicity of it but I have come up against something which seems it must have an elegant solution but I am not creating anything like an elegant solution!!

The scenario is that I want to go off to a 3rd party web service to get some information (in a separate thread) and at the same time search locally. Then merge the results UNLESS the webservice times out and I will take only the information from the local results.

Therefore I want to introduce a timeout to the Observable section in here:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            var o = Observable.Start(DoSeparateThreadCall);

            DoCallInThisThread();

            o.First();

            Console.WriteLine("the End");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DoSeparateThreadCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started in separate thread call");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Ended in separate thread call");
        }

        static void DoCallInThisThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started in this thread call");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Ended in this thread call");
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone done anything similar? It seems like it must be a reasonably common thing to do, i.e. if the 3rd party call times out do X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless on how you want to want the timeout to occur (Rx controlled or client proxy), you probably want to use `Catch`:

```
public IObservable<IList<SearchResult>> GetSearchResults()
{
    return Observable.ForkJoin(
        GetRemoteSearchResults(),
        GetLocalSearchResults()
        )
        .Select(MergeSearchResults);
}

private IObservable<IList<SearchResult>> GetRemoteSearchResults()
{
    return GetSearchResultsFromWebService()
        .Timeout(RemoteTimeOut)
        .Catch<IList<SearchResult>, TimeoutException>(
            Observable.Return((IList<SearchResult>)new List<SearchResult>())
        );
}

private IObservable<IList<SearchResult>> MergeSearchResults(
    IList<SearchResult>[] allResults)
{
    var localResults = allResults[0];
    var remoteResults = allResults[1];

    if (remoteResults.Count == 0)
    {
        return localResults;
    }
    else
    {
        var mergedResults = new List<SearchResult>();
        // merge

        return mergedResults;
    }
}
```

If you want to use your webservice's timeout, just catch that exception type instead.

Comment: Thanks Richard, looks like a good solution. I will check it tomorrow morning!

Comment: No problemss. I just noticed you're using .NET 3.5 and so do not have covariance. To get around this, I've added a cast to the `Observable.Return` call.